# Logics of proper class sized Kripke frames

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, modal-logic

The following can be stated as a sentence of Morse-Kelley set theory:

> If L is the logic of a proper class sized Kripke frame, then L is the logic of a set sized Kripke frame.

It follows from a $\Pi^1_1$ reflection principle (or suitable large cardinal assumption). But I was wondering if this is something that might follow from standard results about frame validity and so be a theorem of MK? And if not, what is the consistency strength of this principle?

Comment: What exactly is "second order $\mathsf{ZFC}$" here? Do you mean some appropriate class theory like $\mathsf{MK}$, or do you really mean the second-order-logic version of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Comment: I meant second order ZFC: an axiomatic system of second order logic with single universally quantified axioms instead of the replacement and separation schemas. I don't think there's much difference mathematically between it and Morse Kelley though, in the sense that you can translate straightforwardly between them. (I'll find a reference for that later.)

Comment: I thought second order ZFC was categorical, analogously to the Peano axioms in second order logic.  No first-order theory with infinite models can be like that, e.g. because of Löwenheim-Skolem.

Comment: OK, I think the question of what counts as a "second order" set theory is distracting, so I've just reformulated the question in terms classes in Morse-Kelley.

Comment: @none It's not (necessarily) categorical, it has $V_\kappa$ as standard models for all inaccessible $\kappa$.

Comment: IIRC frame validity is $\Pi^1_1$-complete by results of Thomason (?) from the 70s, thus it may well turn out that $\Pi^1_1$-reflection is actually necessary.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, yes that was my suspicion. I should read the Thomason now, but I was wondering in what sense frame validity is $\Pi_1^1$-complete, since there are even first-order conditions that cannot be expressed in terms of frame validity.

Comment: I believe [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.19750210114) is the Thomason paper @EmilJeřábek mentioned above.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, this is it. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I remembered [you finding it for me](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120694/how-are-modal-logic-and-graph-theory-related/120700#comment310423_120700) some years ago!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Wow, I completely forgot about that. I guess we are even, then.

Comment: Thank you both for tracking that paper down. I also found [this](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/mkracht/html/kuzn.pdf) paper by Marcus Kracht that seems to directly answer my question: he describes a normal modal logic $\Sigma$ that has a sentence that it satisfiable in a $\Sigma$-frame only if that frame has inaccessible cardinality.